# HTTP Status code for language redirect

Tags: php, http, redirect, seo

I wonder which HTTP Status code I should have to send in language redirects.

I have the following php code to redirect via HTTP headers to most important language in Accept-Language browser header.

```
<?
$langs = array();

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
    // break up string into pieces (languages and q factors)
    preg_match_all('/([a-z]{1,8}(-[a-z]{1,8})?)\s*(;\s*q\s*=\s*(1|0\.[0-9]+))?/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], $lang_parse);

    if (count($lang_parse[1])) {
        // create a list like "en" => 0.8
        $langs = array_combine($lang_parse[1], $lang_parse[4]);

        // set default to 1 for any without q factor
        foreach ($langs as $lang => $val) {
            if ($val === '') $langs[$lang] = 1;
        }

        // sort list based on value 
        arsort($langs, SORT_NUMERIC);
    }
}

// look through sorted list and use first one that matches our languages
foreach ($langs as $lang => $val) {
    if (strpos($lang, 'ca')===0) {
    header("location: ca/");
    exit;
    } else if (strpos($lang, 'es')===0) {
    header("location: es/");
    exit;
    } 
  echo "$lang => $val<br>";
}
// show default site or prompt for language
header("location: en/");

?>
```

Related question: [HTTP status for functional redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273970/http-status-for-functional-redirect)

Maybe 300, 301, 302, 303? Why?

**EDIT**

Google recently published this:
 http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html

I found  this:

> HTTP STATUS 300 Multiple Choices
>
> The requested resource corresponds to any one of a set of
>   representations, each with its own specific location, and agent-
>   driven negotiation information (section 12) is being provided so that
>   the user (or user agent) can select a preferred representation and
>   redirect its request to that location.
>
> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity
>   containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s) from
>   which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate. The
>   entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-
>   Type header field. Depending upon the format and the capabilities of
>
> the user agent, selection of the most appropriate choice MAY be
>   performed automatically. However, this specification does not define
>   any standard for such automatic selection.
>
> If the server has a preferred choice of representation, it SHOULD
>   include the specific URI for that representation in the Location
>   field; user agents MAY use the Location field value for automatic
>   redirection. This response is cacheable unless indicated otherwise.

And this:

> HTTP Error 300 - Multiple choices
>
> Introduction
>
> Your Web server thinks that the URL provided by the client (e.g. your
>   Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) is not specific enough, and a
>   further selection needs to be made from a number of choices.
>
> This is typically the case where the URL represents a high level
>   grouping of which lower level selections need to be made e.g. a
>   directory within which the user must select a particular file to
>   access.
>
> 300 errors in the HTTP cycle
>
> Any client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) goes
>   through the following cycle when it communicates with the Web server:
>
> Obtain an IP address from the IP name of the site (the site URL
>   without the leading 'http://'). This lookup (conversion of IP name to
>   IP address) is provided by domain name servers (DNSs). Open an IP
>   socket connection to that IP address. Write an HTTP data stream
>   through that socket. Receive an HTTP data stream back from the Web
>   server in response. This data stream contains status codes whose
>   values are determined by the HTTP protocol. Parse this data stream for
>   status codes and other useful information. This error occurs in the
>   final step above when the client receives an HTTP status code that it
>   recognises as '300'.
>
> Fixing 300 errors - general
>
> The first thing you should do is check your URL in a Web browser. If
>   you see some kind of Web page prompting you for further
>   action/choices, then your URL as it stands is not detailed enough for
>   the Web server to process.
>
> Fixing 300 errors - CheckUpDown
>
> You should never see this error on your CheckUpDown account if you
>   gave us a top-level URL (such as www.isp.com) to check. If it does
>   occur for a top-level URL, it is highly likely that the Web server
>   software has been incorrectly programmed or configured. If you have
>   given us a low-level URL (such as www.isp.com/products/index.html) to
>   check, then it is likely that this URL is not accessible even via a
>   Web browser.
>
> The first thing you should do is check your URL in a Web browser. If
>   you see a sensible Web page, then it may indicate a defect in our
>   software. If however you see some kind of Web page prompting you for
>   further action/choices, then your URL is not suitable for us to check,
>   because our system can not possibly make this kind of choice.
>
> Please contact us directly (email preferred) whenever you encounter
>   300 errors. Only we can resolve them for you. If there is a defect in
>   our software we will fix it. If however your URL is fundamentally unsuitable for us to 
>   use, you need to change it on your CheckUpDown account (start by
>   clicking the 'Manage' button).

Answer (score 7):

Google uses `302 Found` for redirection to localised page.

Also, in [this article](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2014/05/creating-right-homepage-for-your#automatically-redirect-users-or-dynamically-serve-the-appropriate-html-content-depending-on-users-location-and-language-settings) from the Google Search Central Blog (posted in 2014), it explicitly says:

> To automatically serve the appropriate HTML content to your users depending on their location and language settings, you will do that by using server-side `302` redirects.

However, it's always good to check what selected response should do and what it is intended for and does it affect caching:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-redirection-3xx

Comment: Yes, use `302 Found` for the redirect. Also see https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/208277013

Answer (score 4):

You could serve every language under the same url and then use content-negotiation of the `Accept-Language` header, but I wouldn't recommend that.

I would rather suggest that on your web sites root url, you issue a redirect (303 - See Other) to a language sub page (E.g. `/en`). When you do that, respond with a `Vary` header, that specifies `Accept-Language` (And any other relevant headers, such as `Cookie`). That way, any intermediaries (proxies, caches) will be able to cache the response. I would specifically *not* issue a 301, since you still want links to point to the root url. On the language-specific page, I would put a `rel="canonical"` to the root url.

See also these threads:

- [How does Google treat HTTP response 303?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=7f545a23e5276203&hl=en)
- [Canonical URLs and Content Negotiation](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=2cd26f69da683a03)

Comment: I will research this 2 links, but for now... Is it possible to output a list of 'Location headers for each language' and let browser decide?

Comment: The browser has already decided, in a way, in that it sent a prioritised list in the request (The `Accept-Language` header). The `Vary: Accept-Language` response-header specifies that this was the basis for the decision.

Comment: Are you sure that a Vary header is necessary? I don't see any multilanguage site that respond with the Accept-Language Vary header.

Comment: @Jordy No, and it would seem likely that it's ignored by most clients as they generally do a poor job of interpreting headers right. It seems like right thing to do though.

Comment: Thank you, another question: my site structure is like http://www.example.com/en/ and http://www.example.com/nl/. Where to respond with the Accept-Language header? On each page?

Comment: `Accept-Language` is a request header, so you shouldn't respond with it. The proper response header would be `Content-Language`. You should send this on all pages, where it should match the actual content language of the page.

Comment: Also, you should probably put multiple canonical meta.tags on each page to point to the other language versions, assuming that the pages can be mapped 1:1 between language version. See here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Possibly `HTTP 300 "Multiple Choices"` as it's technically the same data/document but available in multiple languages?

Comment: The 300 status code should be used to respond with a document listing all choices if negotiation failed.

Comment: Yes - but isn't that what's being done (looking at the code)? If the language is auto-detected from the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE then do that - otherwise there's a comment that states `// show default site or prompt for language` ... it was that "prompt for language" bit that made me think 300 would be "right" ... although, as with almost anything in programming, there are always multiple values for "right" ;)

Comment: Ok. I'm going to research that and I will tell you.

Comment: I edited my original question. I'm not convinced of this solution. What I need to do as to say "negotation" hasn't fail? I have to send 300 where i redirect english as default language and spanish (not default) too?

Comment: jrosell: with 300, the client picks. If you want to automate it, you need 301/302/307. Also keep in mind that you really don't need to redirect (serving different content for the same URI based on Accept-Language is possible, too)

Answer (score 1):

I think the questions is more related what you want to achieve:

1: Your index page should be the landing page for your visitor, and you want that page the be indexed by search engines.

Pros: You have one entry page for all your visitors that can host additional information before the actual landing page. However, it will not have content for a specific language.

Cons: You don't have any content pages for all languages on search engines.

2: The actual translated page should be the landing page, and if possible your visitors should end up at the translated page directly if that is possible. The redirect page is only for visitors that ended up straight at your site by entering hostname in the addressbar.

Pros: You have multiple "landing pages" for each individual language, which helps scoring and clickthrough.

Cons: You don't have a generic landing page.

There are more pros and cons on these two choices, but I can't think of it right now.

If option 1: use a 302 because you still want it to be part of search index.
if option 2: use a 301 because you don't want that page to be indexed. Alternatively, use a noindex on the language select page.

Afaik, Google only takes into account, 301, 302 and 307 (temporary maintenance), and I think it consider everything else as 302 (seems most logical). As far as the browser goes, I think it doesn't matter. It might affect caching, but I think nowadays they are pretty aggressive in caching even 3xx responses.

Comment: I want each language page indexed in each language search index. (i.e. Search in spanish returns /es/, search in english return /en/). Do you think i should have / as home page for the default language? Should I use rel=canonical then?

Comment: You could use canonical for this if you want, but not necessarily. If you always redirect visitors to /en with a 301, google will only index the language urls.

Comment: Do you think it make sense to have 301 according to content negotiation?

Comment: Content negotiation serves different content based on certain factors, a 301 is not that. The upside with a 301 is that external links that would point to /, would instead give weight to the destination page that google would get (probably /en) as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 303, because it have the most suitable formulation - See Other (302-Moved Temporarily and 301 - Moved Permanently).
Actually HTTP 303 response in this situation to ensure that the web user's browser can then safely refresh the server response without causing the initial HTTP POST request to be resubmitted.

Comment: Of all the choices, 303 is the one that's definitely incorrect.

For instance, if you PUT to a negotiated resource, you don't want the HTTP library to change the request to GET after the redirect.